# how to write for loop and if statement to fill specific value

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to fill a new column in my data frame based on specific condition.
From column is already timedelta dtype.

```
 for index in df:
        if From >= "07:00:00" & From <"15:00:00"
           df.shift="A"
```

I get a syntax error.

My dataframe looks like this (inferred from comment):

```
From,shift
00:00:00,None
00:30:00,None
01:00:00,None
01:30:00,None
02:00:00,None
[...]
```

Comment: would help to see a snippet of the dataframe. It is not clear to me what `From` is or what is in the `df` or how the timestamps are being handled.

Comment: From         shift
 00:00:00    None
 00:30:00    None
01:00:00     None
01:30:00    None
02:00:00    None

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ":" to the end of the "if" statement. It is missing in your example.

Comment: not working i tried this code: for index in df.From:
    {if (From >= ("07:00:00")) & (From < ("15:00:00")):
    print(df.head(10))   }   ,,, 07:00:00 is timedelta in my dataset